# Direct Injection, Factory Pattern, Singleton Pattern

Tags: design-patterns, singleton, factory, factory-pattern

My program has a window where to draw and works on a model (a class). Many other classes (objects) at runtime will use these two. For this reason I need to keep a reference to them. Until now, I just kept two pointers as member variables in my main GUI class, but now I would like to use a better strategy. Singleton pattern seemed to be ideal, but many says that it is better not to use. Alternatives seems to be Direct Injection (which I think is not ideal for my case) or other patterns, like the Factory Pattern. But Factory pattern creates stuff and does not keep references to the created stuff, or am I wrong? Are there other patterns that could help me to have some kind of global container that keeps references to objects that many other objects will use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you need to change how the references are kept. The main GUI class keeps track of what is created as part of the application, which is perfectly reasonable.

Using Singleton basically means "Create some other object than the main GUI class that keeps track of which objects are created. Now instead of asking the GUI class, and object will ask the Singleton instead. If they already ask the GUI class, it fulfills the same purpose as a Singleton does.

So, if you code looks like this:

```
object.myMethod {
<...>
  draw(mainGuiClass.textWindow, bla, bla, bla);
```

...and textWindow is static, you are probably already using mainGuiClass as a Singleton.

If what happens instead is that methods are invoked like this object.someMethod(mainGui.textWindow, bla, bla, bla) or your objects are created with a reference to mainGuiClass or mainGuiClass.textWindow, you are using some kind of Injection.

Does this help?

Comment: Yes, you are practically thinking the same way I do, I wanted just to be sure that there is no other reasonable way.. What I did now, is to create a separate class, Global, that I instantiate in the constructor of my main GUI class and to which I give every object I will need later. It is practical, because I am taking away my application logic stuff from the main GUI class, leaving it to handle only events like button clicks, ... and I have now a separate class that holds all the objects other objects will need in the future. Everything else is injected by accessing the Global data

Comment: Personally I prefer to configure objects with their subjects (here, references to windows or the central guiObject) at creation, as it makes unit testing faster and easier in my setup. A point for using Factory is that you can do delayed creation of objects to cut down on startup time, but then again you can do the same in your GUI class.

Comment: Your real goal here is to have a lot of independent, generic parts that are assembled, configured and cordinated by the main application class. Whether you collect all the creation/configuration/coordination in one class or in several is up to you. In the generic bits you should avoid hardcoded references to the main GUI class or sigleton, as it makes reuse harder and tends to promote code that is not generic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Window and Model will be single instance - use Singletone. Did i understand right, you want them in single instance?

Comment: I just want a global place where to hold my data that will be later used by other objects..

Comment: So, you do not want use factory? Because of factory can make a lot of same objects. I think, Singletone will feet your needs.

Comment: Yes I know, but as Anders said, it just moving a problem to somewhere else. If you create something and you need to keep track of it, then just declare it as member variable in that class and inject everything else